# How do I keep my error message from flashing twice?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a little error mechanism that displays an error by fading it in, waiting a few secs, and fading out. It works if I let it run through the whole process, but if I quickly click on a lot of things that show errors, here is where it goes wrong.

The error message shows, then fades in and out. So I tried solving this by adding a var called `is_fading` to check the current status of the error, but it didnt work. Here is my code:

```
errors: {
    is_fading: false,

    render: function (msg) {
        GroupManagement.error.html(msg);

        if (GroupManagement.errors.is_fading == true)
        {
            GroupManagement.error.delay(1500).fadeOut();
            GroupManagement.errors.is_fading = false;
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            GroupManagement.error.fadeIn('normal', function()
            {
                GroupManagement.errors.is_fading = true;
                $(this).delay(1500).fadeOut();
                GroupManagement.errors.is_fading = false;
            });
        }
    }
},
```

As mentioned before, this is just what I thought would solve the problem, but doesn't. Does anyone know why?

Comment: fadeOut gets 2 parameter: duration, and complete. The complete, is actually a callback function that gets called when the "fadeOut" operation is completed. So, you need to change your code and set the is_fading flag based on this...

Comment: Thank you Mehdi, it worked when I added a callback function to fadeOut :)

Comment: @Mehdi  try to add a code answer so that OP can mark you and future visitors got help.

Answer (score 0):

Credit goes to @Mehdi, the answer is:

```
errors: {
    is_fading: false,

    render: function (msg) {
        GroupManagement.error.html(msg);

        if (GroupManagement.errors.is_fading == true)
        {
            GroupManagement.error.delay(1500).fadeOut('', function () {
                GroupManagement.errors.is_fading = false;
            });
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            GroupManagement.error.fadeIn('normal', function()
            {
                GroupManagement.errors.is_fading = true;
                $(this).delay(1500).fadeOut('', function () {
                    GroupManagement.errors.is_fading = false;
                });

            });
        }
    }
},
```